# Deployer Microservice url is not working

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion, deployer, microservices

I have installed a Deployer combined microservice as per the SDL documentation provided for SDL 8.5. When I start the service, the service is running but when I try to access the Deployer url Ex: http://localhost:8084/httpupload, it is not working. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you see on the browser, when you try to access this URL ? and is there anything in the logs ? Can you also confirm that, the port is accessible  on your machine

Comment: I see that site cant be reached error.There is nothing written in logs when hit the url. The service is running in port 8084 only and when i run the below command,the result shows the port 8084.                                                        sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN                                                                                    
tcp6       0      0 :::8084                 :::*                    LISTEN      6201/java

Comment: change the log level of deployer to TRACE , restart the service , hit the service url again and then see, if there is any logs are generated "Make sure to rollback the log level to original "

Comment: Could you please check the KB article and apply the latest hot fix for deployer service, perhaps apply CD_8.5.0.3922 HF. As everyone suggested that, the port might be blocked due to firewall rule or the particular port must have used by some other application. You can try to change the port for httpupload and give a try. Make sure you can change the log level to DEBUG mode and later on put it original to ERROR mode.

Comment: This was a port firewall issue and we are running the service in 80 port now and issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in KB article, issue was due to customer firewall blocking applications not running on port 80.  Port 80 can be used for the Deployer if needed.

https://gateway.sdl.com/communityknowledge?articleName=000011710[1](https://gateway.sdl.com/communityknowledge?articleName=000011710)